# Serving HTML with C#

Tags: c#, http, web

I have experience developing websites with `PHP` and `nodeJS` backends so I know how the back end script (`PHP, nodeJS`) interacts with the front end scripts (`HTML, Javascript, CSS, LESS ect`) and how the `web server` functionality fits in in these environments.

I also have some brief experience using `C# MVC` to create websites so I know how it is done in `C#` with a framework.

My question is how would a person create seperatea web application using C# WITHOUT any sort of framework.

What can be used as a `HTTP server`?
Are there any `C#` classes which setup a `HTTP server` (like `http` in `nodeJS express`) or do you need separate C# comparable software (like `apache` for `php`)

How does the back end code interface with the front end? 
(In `PHP` you can write text, html, scripts or anything else directly into the HTML but I dont think you can do this with `C#`)

Remember my question is specifically in regard to situation where you are NOT using a web framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FastCGI implementation to run your C# program using Apache or nginx:

- https://github.com/gigi81/sharpfastcgi
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/fcgidotnet/
- https://github.com/wmeyer/SharpCGI
- https://github.com/mzabani/FastCgiNet

See also [Is there a .NET FastCGI library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075859/is-there-a-net-fastcgi-library)